# DOM element index

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have the following DOM element, how can I get the index of the parent element if the child element is clicked? When I display document.getElementsByClassName('b-btn b-btn-type-a b-btn-emph') in console, it return input.b-btn b-btn-type-a b-btn-emph having two index. Code viewable at https://jsfiddle.net/Z7R5n/127/

```
<div id="shop-cart-313232f0-089c-11e2-8556-005056bd629f" ng-repeat="cart in data.carts" ng-controller="ShopCartCtrl" class="ng-scope">
      <div id="error_inventory_banner_313232f0-089c-11e2-8556-005056bd629f" class="">
        <!-- ngRepeat: warning in cart.warnings -->
      </div>
      <div id="cart_313232f0-089c-11e2-8556-005056bd629f" ng-show="cart.items" class="b-container b-mod-mall-order-table">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://secure.rakuten.com.my/checkout/login/?l-id=my_cart_checkout_1" autocomplete="off" method="post" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
          <div class="b-order-index">
            <b>
              <span class="b-text-xlarge">Shop: </span>
              <span class="b-text-xlarge ng-binding" ng-bind="cart.shopName">Bagstation</span>
              <span class="b-text-stg b-pd"><a ng-href="http://styles.my/testrakutenGTM/gtm.php" href="http://styles.my/testrakutenGTM/gtm.php">go to shop page</a></span>
            </b>
            <input type="hidden" id="shop_name_313232f0-089c-11e2-8556-005056bd629f" value="Bagstation">
          </div>
          .......


          </div>
          <!-- ngIf: cart.items.outOfCart -->
        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- ngIf: cart.emptyCartHtml -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('b-btn b-btn-type-a b-btn-emph')
```

returns an array so if you want to access the different elements you have to use the operator [ ]. Then you can access your object's properties with . (like .value).

Comment: hi Pleasure. can I read the index of array when user clicked on the childnode? Example let say array [0,1] and user clicked on the childnode of the array [1] and I want to get the parent element of array [1].